# How to remove columns with repeated name but keeping data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe for a dataset where the attributes are English words. After stemming the words, I have multiple columns with the same name. Here are sample data [snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXBsM.png), after stemming, the `accept, acceptable and accepted` become `accept`. I want to use bitwise_or on all columns with the same name and delete the repeated one. I tried this code

```
import numpy
from nltk.stem import *
import pandas as pd
ps = PorterStemmer()
dataset = pd.read_csv('sampleData.csv')
stemmed_words = []

for w in list(dataset):
    stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

dataset.columns = stemmed_words
new_word = stemmed_words[0]

for w in stemmed_words:
    if new_word == w:
         numpy.bitwise_or(dataset[new_word], dataset[w])
         del dataset[w]
     else:
         new_word = w

print(dataset)
```

The problem is that when the for loop execute

```
del dataset['accept']
```

It deletes all the column with this name. and I do not know in advance that how many columns will have the same name and this code generate an exception KeyError: 'accept'

I want to apply bitwise_or on all three `accept` columns, save it into a new column named 'accept' and del the old columns.

I hope that I will not be downvoted this time

Here is sample data:

```
able  abundance  academy  accept  accept  accept  access  accommodation  accompany Class
   0          0        0       0       0       1       1              0          0     C
   0          0        0       1       0       0       0              0          0     A
   0          0        0       0       1       0       0              0          0     H
   0          0        0       0       0       1       0              1          0     G
   0          0        0       1       0       0       0              0          0     G
```

The output should be

```
Class  able  abundance  academy  accept  access  accommodation  accompany
    C     0          0        0       1       1              0          0
    A     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
    H     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
    G     0          0        0       1       0              1          0
    G     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can group by column names (`axis=1`).

**Data Frame:**

```
In [101]: df
Out[101]:
   able  abundance  academy  accept  accept  accept  access  accommodation  accompany Class
0     0          0        0       0       0       1       1              0          0     C
1     0          0        0       1       0       0       0              0          0     A
2     0          0        0       0       1       0       0              0          0     H
3     0          0        0       0       0       1       0              1          0     G
4     0          0        0       1       0       0       0              0          0     G
```

**Solution:**

```
In [103]: df.pop('Class').to_frame() \
     ...:   .join(df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).any(1).mul(1))
Out[103]:
  Class  able  abundance  academy  accept  access  accommodation  accompany
0     C     0          0        0       1       1              0          0
1     A     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
2     H     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
3     G     0          0        0       1       0              1          0
4     G     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
```

or even better solution ([@ayhan, thank you for the hint!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830707/how-to-remove-columns-with-repeated-name-but-keeping-data#comment74699578_43830784)):

```
In [114]: df = df.pop('Class').to_frame().join(df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).max())

In [115]: df
Out[115]:
  Class  able  abundance  academy  accept  access  accommodation  accompany
0     C     0          0        0       1       1              0          0
1     A     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
2     H     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
3     G     0          0        0       1       0              1          0
4     G     0          0        0       1       0              0          0
```

Comment: can you explain this approach a little more? It is not giving the desired output. it is not grouping the column with the same name. I replaced the the for loop in OP with your 'df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).any(1).mul(1)'

Comment: @Abrar, please provide a small __reproducible__ sample (3-5 rows) data set (in text/CSV format - so we could copy and paste it) and a desired data set [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43830707/edit)

Comment: @MaxU I think instead of mul the OP is looking for groupby.sum (since these are binary, their sum will act like `any` - 1 if any of them is 1.)

Comment: @ayhan, thank you for your comment! I'm not sure, because i don't see any number > 1 in the desired data set...

Comment: @Ayhan The sum is not appropriate as I may get more than '1' as a result in certain situations while I need either 0 or 1  value.

Comment: @Abrar Then `groupby.max`  should work? If all 0, it will return zero. If at least one of them is 1, it will return 1.

Comment: @ayhan, yeah, that's much better and that will work! Thank you for the hint! I'll add it to the answer...

Comment: @Abrar, glad we could help :)